# About equal substitutions

Tags: definition, first-order-logic, substitution

When we say that two substitutions, say $\theta,\sigma$ agree on the variables of a term $t$ what exactly do we mean ? Is it that both substitution act on the same variables and substitute them with the same terms?

That is $\theta=  \lbrace x_1/u_1,x_2/u_2,...,x_n/u_n\rbrace$ and  $\sigma=  \lbrace x_1/u_1,x_2/u_2,...,x_n/u_n\rbrace$

Or the substitute terms don't really have to be the same? I was confused when i checked the wikipedia lemma about substitution that said :

"Two substitutions are considered equal if they map each variable to structurally equal result terms" [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_%28logic%29#First-order_logic)

Comment: Think at a *substitution* as a function that maps **all** variables (with their "natural" ordering) into *terms*. To say that $\theta$ and $\sigma$ "agree on" the variables of $t$ means exactly that if $x_i$ occurs in $t$, then $\theta(x_i)=\sigma(x_i)$.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I guess that this is a more intuitive description of the first case i mentioned.